# Jar versioning in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, maven-3

On each maven build or release, how to get new jar version in Jenkins.  I have tried it in Jenkins but only getting same jar file name as it is in pom file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [maven-exec-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to print the version to stdout or write it in a file:

`mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec`